# Do these macros evaluate to the same code using gcc at compile-time?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, macros

Of course this is going to be a function of the compiler you are using, but I figured this would be a simple question to answer.

```
#define UBRRVAL(baud) (F_CPU/(16*baud)-1)
```

As compared with

```
#define UBRRVAL(baud) (F_CPU/16/baud-1)
```

I know that the latter is going to evaluate to (assuming F_CPU = 20000000):

```
#define UBRRVAL(baud) (12500000/baud-1)
```

Considering the forced precidence by the parenthesis I was curious to know if most compilers (gcc in particular) would evaluate the former expression equivalently to the latter at compile-time.

This is code that is going into an embeddded system, so if these expressions are not evaluated at compile-time equivalently, then the latter is more efficient; a single division at run-time is more efficient than a division *and* a mulitplication of course.

Comment: what happened when you tried?

Comment: Well both expressions work at run-time, but I was not able to successfully look at any generated code via a list file or anything.

Comment: They could be different if `F_CPU` weren't an even multiple of `16`.  Try both and peek at the assembly code (`gcc -S`).

Comment: There's also the fact that the compiler can't usually assume `(16*baud)` won't overflow...

Comment: You might use constexpr (C++11) and inline.

Comment: @aschepler Interesting. Why would it make a difference if the division were not even? Do you mean in terms of integer division as oposed to floating-point code being generated? But default, what is the length allocated to that multiplication? (16*baud). I suppose it would be perhaps an in for 16 and baud would likely promote this multiplication to whatever its datatype is?

Comment: @aschepler: Wrong, the compiler can assume that. Per the standard, such overflow is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @MSalters Not if `baud` has type `unsigned int`.  Plus many compilers, including gcc, provide implementation-defined guarantees for signed overflow.

Comment: Indeed, the generated code is slightly more efficient for unsigned integer types. But looking at `int`, the first option emits an additional `sal` instruction that is missing in the code generated for the second option. At least in g++ 4.8.1, with either -O2 or -O3. I don't really know how you expect us to answer this, though. You have to test it on the compiler you're using for *your embedded system*, with the optimization options that are available. And the values you expect to use it with.

Comment: @aschepler In this context, `baud` doesn't have a type. It's a simple text replacement parameter, and could be fed anything at all...

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer, no.

Because neither macro is fully parenthesized, there are cases where the two are very different.

Consider `UBRRVAL(2+1)`. The first would expand to `(F_CPU/(16*2+1)-1)`, which is equivalent to `F_CPU/33 - 1`. The second would expand to `(F_CPU/16/2+1-1)`, which is equivalent to `F_CPU/32`. Not the same at all.

Of course, it probably isn't meant to be called with an expression, just with a single constant value, but there's nothing to prevent it, and as such, someone will do it sometime in the future. One of the many evils of macros. I would recommend using a short (static) inline function (or `constexpr` as suggested in comments, if this is using a recent enough C++ compiler) instead...

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, yes. Within the specific constraints given both will be fully evaluated at compile time.

Parentheses force precedence but they do not force order of evaluation, except to the extent defined by the "as if" rule. You cannot be sure what code will be emitted if the expression is slightly more complicated so it is not evaluated at compile time. This may well depend on the specific processor.

As a side point, on most processors a 4 bit shift left or shift right are the same cost, and if the baud rate is a power of two the compiler is likely to generate shift operations.

[And be careful about parenthesising macro arguments. You got away with it this time, but only just.]